# Mysql Delete From Query

Tags: mysql

How do i delete both image_media_set and media_set table in the below
where the count is greater than 1.

```
SELECT media_set.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   image_media_set
        WHERE  image_media_set.media_set_id = media_set.id) AS imageCount
FROM   media_set
       INNER JOIN image_media_set
         ON media_set.id = image_media_set.media_set_id
WHERE  image_media_set.image_id = 6405;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the same than always delete the registry, is it not?

Is the COUNT really necessary?

Try this:

```
   DELETE FROM media_set, image_media_set
   WHERE image_media_set.media_set_id = media_set.id
   AND image_media_set.image_id = 6405;
```

Comment: i need to delete where the count i greater than one